# Difference between transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease and transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug task?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I run **assembleDebug**, debug apk of the application is generated successfully but on trying **assembleRelease**, it results into failure at **transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug** task.

Following is the snippet of the exact error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
Program type already present: android.support.annotation.AnimRes
```

I would like to know why this error doesn't occur with **assembleDebug**?

What exactly is the difference between **transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug** and **transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease**?

P.S. I have tried clean and rebuild of the project.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this to happen is [multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) . Probably in gradle in your debug version you have

```
    `multidexEnabled true
```

which lets you bypass the 64k limit for your debug version hence the apk is created successfully. What usually happens for production code is you don't enable multidex and use [proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) to reduce the referenced code size to not bypass the 64k limit.

Comment: If that is the case, how can I enable `multidex` for production?

Comment: Generally it is not recommend to enable multidex for production, but if you want to  add it, you can just state in build.gradle(app level) under buildTypes { release {